# JPA/ManyToOne/JoinColumn with a database View : how to avoid Foreign Key generation?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I have a @ManyToOne association, the target entity maps a database view.
JPA/Hibernate tries to generate a Foreign Key constraint between the table and the view, which is not possible (so I get an exception at each start of application). How to avoid this ?

```
@Entity
public class ThirdParty{
  @Id
  String id=UUID.randomUUID().toString();

  String bookId;

  @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
  @MapsId("bookId")
  @JoinColumn(name="bookId", referencedColumnName = "cid", foreignKey = @ForeignKey(name = "none"))
  private XCompany xCompany;

  //...
}
```

I get this exception :

```
org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.CommandAcceptanceException: Error executing DDL

Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: (conn=1266699) Cannot add foreign key constraint
```

Putting **foreignKey = @ForeignKey(name = "none")** has no effect.

Any idea ?

Comment: Why do you have DDL generation enabled for every time the application starts? If you want to avoid the warning messages, turn it off.

Comment: @Chris : you're right, but we're still in development, so we need it to create new entities/attributes/constraints (and to validate the schema).

Answer (score 0):

The naming used for the foreign key can be reserved words. Did you check this?
For example; The word 'none' is a reserved word for MySQL.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using the name `none`, use `@ForeignKey(ConstraintMode.NO_CONSTRAINT)`